# Multiple charges with PayPal

Tags: php, paypal

I'm looking for a solution to achieve my goal so I will try to explain what I'm looking for....

I would like to create a sales page where I will be able to sale product using PayPal. After successful payment I would like to redirect my client to second sales page where my client will be able to purchase second product. I understand that my client need to authorise on first sales page but I need to charge (create transaction) on second sales page in the background (without authorisation). Is it possible? Is it required to verify transactions twice or maybe there is a way to create second transaction behalf of my client without his interference?

I'm looking for your suggestions...

Comment: Isn't this more like a shopping cart - add all the items to the cart and then pay?

Comment: It is something like that, but I would like to offer second product after first purchase so I need to charge my clients and after that charge one more time if he would like to buy second product.

Comment: a bit late to the party, but it's called post-sale up/cross-sell and requires the first transaction to be made. I'm looking for a solution too but haven't found anything so far. If the second transaction is <15% value of the first (and max $75) you could just create and authorization and capture later - this allows you to capture 115% (max additional $75) of the original amount. But not useful for most cases here